# Did Vishnu become Trivikrama, other than during his Vamana avatar?

Tags: vishnu, identification-request

We know about Vishnu assumed the form of Trivikrama during his Vamana avatar. However, did Vishnu assumed this form other than it?

Comment: its still believed in madhava tradition is leg still up in bramhaloka and ganges being poured into his feet by brahma deva he had not done with it. tiruvikrama avatara is supposed to be there throughout till the ganges runs in the earth only thing is we are not able see his legs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the fight between Indra and Vrtra.

**Rig Veda 8.100.12.:**

> 12. Step forth with wider stride, my comrade Visnu; make room, Dyaus, for the leaping of the lightning. Let us slay Vrtra, let us free the rivers let them flow loosed at the command of Indra.

**Rig Veda 1.22.17-18.:**

> 17. Through all this world strode Viṣṇu; thrice his foot he planted, and the whole
>     Was gathered in his footstep's dust.
> 18. Viṣṇu, the Guardian, he whom none deceiveth, made three steps; thenceforth<.
>     Establishing his high decrees.

**Rig Veda 1.154.1.:**

> 1. I WILL declare the mighty deeds of Viṣṇu, of him who measured out the earthly regions,
>    Who propped the highest place of congregation, thrice setting down his footstep, widely striding.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..